# Youtube views not registering through Facebook

Tags: facebook, view, youtube, embed

Youtube does not count views when videos are autoplayed, i.e. when they have the parameter autoplay=1 at the end of the url like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r7wHMg5Yjg&autoplay=1

now when the videos are embedded inside facebook the code is:

`<embed width="398" height="224" flashvars="width=398&amp;height=224" wmode="opaque" salign="tl" allowscriptaccess="never" allowfullscreen="true" scale="scale" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="swf_u285641_8" id="swf_u285641_8" style="" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TxzVGR5U4Lc?version=3&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">`

because of this the views when a user shares on their facebook does not get counted properly. This has huge marketing ramifications, as youtube views are very important to grow organically, and facebook is definately the biggest medium of word of mouth.

This problem has been confirmed by a Google Employee, so is facebook working on something to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I guess the makeshift solution is to post a screen shot with a link to youtube or your page as long as autoplay=0.

Comment: Actually I did try to pass my own embed parameters through my website and added autoplay=0 at the end, which worked. And now when I click the thumbnail in my facebook feed after sharing, it opens up the youtube embed but does not play it back. If I click on the video, only then it is played. Hopefully will start registering my views at least for those videos which come through my site. However, one disconcerting thing is that facebook still added autoplay=1 after my link like this:

src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TxzVGR5U4Lc?version=3&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=0?autoplay=1"